Why does my MongoDb query in Node.js not return any results?
I have the following cookie cutter code, that just simply looks to select records with a specific field value (that I know exist in my database) with a MongoClient:
await client.connect()

const db = client.db("myDb");

const collection = db.collection("myCollection");

const result = await collection.find({

      "fieldName": "myField"
  },

  {}
)
.toArray();

await client.close();
  
console.log(result);

I know that it works in the case when there is no query, as I successfully could get every data dumped in the result array before, however with the above query, it only writes an empty array to the console, and I could not, for the life of me, figure out why.

please show example for the data you are trying to query

The object you pass to find() is a query predicate and in your case contains a simple "key" : "value" pair. Ensure that the key is the name of the field and value is thing your are trying to match on that field. At the minute you are trying to find a document that has a key named fieldName with a value of the string myField. I suspect that was not your intention. If you still need help post a sample document into the question.
